# How to get text from same Text Field used multiple times in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm trying to get text from a JTextField iterated through my code (apparently, I can't add a different text field from a button). Here's what the "Add Items" button do:

```
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        tf = new JTextField("Name",20);
        tfv = new JTextField("Value", 7); 
        
        p.revalidate();
        p.repaint();   
        
        p.add(tf);
        p.add(tfv);
    }
});
```

It adds two new text fields in the panel using FlowLayout.
Now, I want to get the text given by the user from text fields with each one assigned to a different variable or maybe into an ArrayList by clickin the "OK" button but the getText() method doesn't seem to work.

```
okButton.addActionListener( e -> {
    
        String txt = tfv.getText(); //only captures the text from the last field in the panel

});
```

Can't seem to think of anything right now.

[image]

Comment: I don't see how your spec can work.  If you have several fields, one "OK" button isn't going to work.  You need a way to specify *which* field will be returned, or (probably this one is correct) you should just return *all* the values in a list.

Comment: Looks like you really want to use a JTable since you're displaying and retrieving data in a tabular structure.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels an _editable_ `JTable`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this code when you are reinitializing `tf` and `tfv` in `addButton` you lost the reference to previous defined textfiels

```
tf = new JTextField("Name",20);
tfv = new JTextField("Value", 7);
```

so to solve this problem you need to define an ArrayList to hold reference to all defined textfields and then you can access to all of them:

```
ArrayList<JTextField> arrayNames  = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
ArrayList<JTextField> arrayValues = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tf = new JTextField("Name",20);
        tfv = new JTextField("Value", 7); 
        
        p.revalidate();
        p.repaint();   
        
        p.add(tf);
        p.add(tfv);

        arrayNames.add(tf);
        arrayValues.add(tfv);
    }
});
```

accessing

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (JTextField txtValue : arrayValues) {
            System.out.println(txtValue.getText());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Method [getComponents()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents--) will return all the components in `p` (the `JPanel`).

In order to distinguish each `JTextField`, you can either give each one a unique name via method [setName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName-java.lang.String-) (and retrieve the name via method `getName()`) or set some property using method [putClientProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) (and retrieve the property via method `getClientProperty()`).

For example using `setName()` to set a unique name for each `JTextField`.

```java
private int counter = 0; // class member

addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
        tf = new JTextField("Name",20);
        tf.setName("tf" + counter);
        tfv = new JTextField("Value", 7); 
        tfv.setName("tfv" + counter);
        counter++;
        
        p.revalidate();
        p.repaint();   
        
        p.add(tf);
        p.add(tfv);
    }
});
```

How to identify each `JTextField`:

```java
okButton.addActionListener( e -> {
    Component[] cmpts = p.getComponents();
    for (Component cmpt : cmpts) {
        String name = cmpt.getName();
        if (name.matches("^tf\\d+$") {
            // Code to handle it.
        }
        else if (name.matches("^tfv\\d+$") {
            // Handling code.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That was ingenious. Thank you